# Como posso extrair as informações de um XML que esta armazenado em uma String?

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile

Estou consumindo este [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) de uma [api](/questions/tagged/api) e armazenando seu conteudo ema uma **`String`**

---

Sua estrutura esta desta forma:

```
<opml version="1">
    <head>
        <title>Título</title>
        <status>200</status>
    </head>
    <body>
        <outline type="link" text="op_1" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=1" key="1"/>
        <outline type="link" text="op_2" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=2" key="2"/>
        <outline type="link" text="op_3" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=3" key="3"/>
        <outline type="link" text="op_4" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=4" key="4"/>
        <outline type="link" text="op_5" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=5" key="5"/>
        <outline type="link" text="op_6" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=6" key="6"/>
        <outline type="link" text="op_7" URL="http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=7" key="7"/>
    </body>
</opml>
```

---

Como posso fazer para ler seu type, text e URL de cada outline?

Comment: Quer-me parecer que quer fazer um gênero de decode a esse XML e, com isso, obter essas informações que pretende. Para isso existem diversas ferramentas entre as quais uma bastante utilizada que é o SAX parser. Deixo-lhe um link com [um exemplo de utilização deste parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode fazer uma expressão regular para pegar apenas os dados que você precisa.

No exemplo acima, com esse xml de entrada para capturar o type e a url vc pode fazer desta forma:

```
         String xml =   "<opml version=\"1\">" +
                            "<head>" +
                                "<title>Título</title>" +
                                "<status>200</status>" +
                            "</head>" +
                            "<body>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_1\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=1\" key=\"1\"/>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_2\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=2\" key=\"2\"/>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_3\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=3\" key=\"3\"/>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_4\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=4\" key=\"4\"/>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_5\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=5\" key=\"5\"/>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_6\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=6\" key=\"6\"/>" +
                                "<outline type=\"link\" text=\"op_7\" URL=\"http://dados.com/op.ashx?c=7\" key=\"7\"/>" +
                            "</body>" +
                        "</opml> ";

        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((<(?i)outline).+?((?i)type=\"(.+?)\").+?((?i)url=\"(.+?)\").+?(\\/>))");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(xml);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String type = matcher.group(4);
            String url = matcher.group(6);
            System.out.println("TYPE: " + type);
            System.out.println("URL: " + url);
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Nesta expressão regular cada argumento entre parênteses significa um agrupamento, desta forma o grupo 4 e grupo 6 são os que vc quer filtrar (`type` e `URL`), a expressão `(?i)` pode ser entendida como ignoreCase

Comment: Funcionou, teria alguma indicação de leitura sobre a estrutura que montou em Pattern.compile?

Comment: Sim, vc pode encontrar um material introdutório sobre expressões regulares em http://turing.com.br/material/regex/introducao.html. Existem um material muito bom também com conceitos e códigos no devmedia - http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-basicos-sobre-expressoes-regulares-em-java/27539. Gosto de utilizar o http://rubular.com/ para testar minhas expressões regulares, lembrando que para adaptar a expressão para java vc vai precisar fazer o escape da expressão, neste caso gosto de utilizar http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

Answer (score 0):

Achei outra forma legal de fazer.

Desta forma voce pode fazer a pesquisa por TAG e atributo.

Vou postar caso alguém prefira fazer desta forma.

---

```
private void le_o_xml2(String xml) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

    //LÊ TODAS AS TAG QUE SE CHAMAM "UOTLINE" . . .
    NodeList outline = doc.getElementsByTagName("outline");
    if (outline.getLength() > 0){
        for(int x = 0; x<outline.getLength(); x++) {
            //CONSOME OS ATRIBUTOS DA TAG . . .
            Element err = (Element) outline.item(x);
            System.out.println(err.getAttribute("type"));
            System.out.println(err.getAttribute("url"));
            System.out.println(err.getAttribute("text"));
            System.out.println(err.getAttribute("key"));
        }
    } else {
        // NÃO ENCONTROU NENHUMA TAG . . .
    }

}
```

---